# subprocess.check_ouput() return code

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

I am using subprocess.check_output() to execute some commands on remote machines via Sysinternals PSExec. The issue I'm having is that check_output() raises a CalledProcessError if the command gives a non-zero return code.

PSExec gives the PID of the created process as its return code so obviously I am getting an error every time. Is there a way I can override this error and still check the output of the psexec call? Basically I just need to see the output even though its return code is non-zero.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `subprocess.call` assuming you're not piping stdout/stderr. All that does is run the command, block until it's complete, then return the returncode.

Comment: Thanks, I actually need the output though as a string, not just the return code. I am searching the output for a key word to make sure that it successfully executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> If the exit code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.  The
>   CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
>   attribute and output in the output attribute.

---

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output([...], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    return_code = err.returncode
    output = err.output
```

Comment: Yeah so I tried this... unfortunately for some reason err.returncode works fine but err.ouput is apparently empty (when I print it to the console, it only prints a blank line).

Comment: Perhaps the process is writing to stderr instead of stdout. In that case, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to capture its output as well.

Comment: if you need to keep stdout and stderr separate, you could use `subprocess.Popen` and its `communicate()` method instead of `subprocess.check_output`...

Comment: that did it, apparently the output I was looking for was in STDERR for some reason. Thanks a bunch!